# "meaning" instated of "in meaning of" is correct?

Tags: word-usage

I would like to know if it's correct to use "meaning" instead of "in meaning of". 
For example in the following sentences:

> 1) "The word mater is from Latin, **meaning** mother." vs "The word mater is from Latin, **in meaning of** mother."
>
> 2) "The word pulmon is from Spanish meaning lung." vs "The word pulmon is from Spanish in meaning of lung".

Or it's better to say "it means mother" or "it means lung".

Comment: Not "in meaning of". Do you have an example using this?

Comment: Your question is unclear. I don't recall ever coming across "in meaning of".

Comment: Should it be "in which it means"?

Comment: I edited the question. I hope now I made it clearer.

Comment: "The word mater is from Latin which means mother."---> "The word mater is from Latin meaning mother." You should delete the comma as this is a shortend relative clause. The other ones with "in meaning" seem not right to me. They give the feeling of being foreigner ones!

Answer (score 1):

1. "The word mater is from Latin, meaning mother." Correct.
2. "The word mater is from Latin, in meaning of mother."  Incorrect.
3. "The word mater is from Latin. It means mother."  Correct.